# how to get values from array with a specific rule in numpy

Tags: numpy

For example, I have a array with value [1,2,4,3,6,7,33,2]. I want to get all the values which are bigger than 6. As I know the `numpy.take` can only get values with indices.
Which function should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index into the array with a boolean array index:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,4,3,6,7,33,2])
>>> a > 6
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[a > 6]
array([ 7, 33])
```

If you want the indices where this occurs, you can use `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(a>6)
(array([5, 6]),)
```